# Functions not being executed

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I am super new at coding, taking my first programming class this semester. We have just learned about functions with an assignment to use functions to make a program that calculates the area and perimeter of a rectangle.

When I run the program, nothing happens. I can't figure out why the first function `getInt` isn't being initialized.

As shown in the code below, the user is not being asked to enter either the width or height. Any and all help is appreciated.

```
def getInt(wid, hght):
 if wid <1:
    print("Integer value must be between 1 and 60, please re-enter: ")
 if wid >60:
    print("Integer value must be between 1 and 60, please re-enter: ")
 wid=float(input("Enter the width (1 - 60): "))
 if hght<1:
    print("Integer value must be between 1 and 20, please re-enter: ")
 if hght>20:
    print("Integer value must be between 1 and 20, please re-enter: ")
 hght=float(input("Enter the height (1 - 20: "))
 return wid
 return hght

def calcPerimeter(width, height):
 width=getInt.wid
 height=getInt.hght
 perimeter=2*(width+height) 
 return perimeter

def calcArea(width, height):
 width=getInt.wid
 height=getInt.hght
 area=width*height
 return area

def Main():
 getInt
 calcPerimeter
 calcArea
Main()
```

Comment: You are not calling the functions! Add parentheses and appropriate arguments: `calcPerimeter(arg1, arg1)`

Comment: Having two successive return statements (as in your first function) makes no sense. You will never reach the second return.

Comment: You're calling functions with no arguments, yet you outlined them in your code. It should have arguments in parentheses next to your function calls

Comment: I added the parentheses at the under the Main function and now I get the error: " TypeError: getInt() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'wid' and 'hght' "

Comment: https://www.codementor.io/kaushikpal/user-defined-functions-in-python-8s7wyc8k2  Read This.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments add parentheses:

```
def Main():
 getInt(2, 2)
 calcPerimeter(2, 2)
 calcArea(2, 2)
Main()
```

Comment: Thank you! That has caused the function to actually initialize. A lot of problems are still left to fix but this was the biggest one I think.